How to get data from a form into plugin?
I'm developing a plugin, it have a form into modal boostrap to the user puts data.
When I do click to save, it's return to the same page, and I need to get the info. It's look like...
<form>
<input class="form-control" type="any" id="compraTC" style="margin-left:5px" placeholder="0.0000" required>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnGuardarTC">Guardar Cambios</button>
</form>

if(isset($_POST['btnGuardarTC'])) {        echo $_POST['compraTC'];     } else echo "no hay retorno";
I can't get the new values. Could you help me, please?
Greetings!
Solution! I need to develop more plugins!

You need to include some more information within the <form> tag. It looks like you are using POST within your PHP, so you'll need to specify that within the HTML, as well as the path to the PHP file on your web server.
<form method="POST" action="./path/to/php/file.php">
    <input class="form-control" type="any" id="compraTC" style="margin-left:5px" placeholder="0.0000" required>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnGuardarTC">Guardar Cambios</button>
</form>

I recommend researching this a bit further, since this information should be easily accessible through online tutorials for HTML and PHP.
See here for more information on the <form> tag in HTML: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form.
